# Do all Smart Contracts use the eosio namespace?

Tags: smart-contract, c++

I'm new to creating Smart Contracts on EOS and I've followed a few tutorials (for example the official [Hello World](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/hello-world) guide).

Would someone be able explain why all of the examples seem to use the namespace eosio?

Is it possible to use a different namespace?

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>
using namespace eosio;

class hello : public eosio::contract {
  public:
      using contract::contract;

      /// @abi action 
      void hi( account_name user ) {
         print( "Hello, ", name{user} );
      }
};

EOSIO_ABI( hello, (hi) )
```

If it is possible to use a different namespace, what are some example situations in which you would use one?

If it isn't possible to use a different namespace, is there any reason why this needs to be in the code and couldn't be left for the compiler to add?

Comment: the `eosiolib` is under eosio namespace to avoid collisions and maintain good practices. it's just standard language-agnostic programming practice to namespace imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eosiolib` uses the `eosio` namespace to avoid collisions when imported in a different scope--this is standard programming practice and is not specific to EOSIO. The `using namespace <name>` directive only brings that namespace in the current scope in order to avoid overusing the scope-resolution operator `::`. How you actually use it in the end is just a styling distinction. You can write the same contract in many ways:

**No `using`**

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>

class hello : public eosio::contract {
  public:
      using eosio::contract::contract;

      /// @abi action 
      void hi( account_name user ) {
         eosio::print( "Hello, ", eosio::name{user} );
      }
};

EOSIO_ABI( hello, (hi) )
```

**With `using namespace`**

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
using namespace eosio;

class hello : public contract {
  public:
      using contract::contract;

      /// @abi action 
      void hi( account_name user ) {
         print( "Hello, ", name{user} );
      }
};

EOSIO_ABI( hello, (hi) )
```

**With `using eosio::<name>`**

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>

using eosio::contract;
using eosio::print;
using eosio::name;

class hello : public contract {
  public:
      using contract::contract;

      /// @abi action 
      void hi( account_name user ) {
         print( "Hello, ", name{user} );
      }
};

EOSIO_ABI( hello, (hi) )
```

I personally find the last one most readable as it is clear where every name is coming from, but it requires more typing than the second example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you *have* to use the eosio namespace, but given that your contract will inherit from `eosio::contract`, it would be standard practice to also use the `eosio` namespace.

Comment: but the contract is not namespaced under `eosio` in OP's example. the `using` directive only brings the `eosio` namespace into the local scope so one can write `contract` instead of `eosio::contract` even if the example doesn't actually take advantage of this when inheriting